# write robocopy output to console and log file

Tags: winforms, powershell, logging, robocopy

I have an interactive PowerShell using windows forms, meaning a PowerShell script displays some controls on a form asking for input and finally runs `robocopy`, when the user clicks the button.

This is a simple script displaying the problem. 
You can copy the code, save it to a Power Sell script and run. It needs a:\tmp\tmp folder to successfully run, see the CopyFolder function.

```
function createdMainForm {
    $mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

    $btn.Text = "RoboCopy"

    #register click event   
    $btn.add_click({Add_click})

    $mainForm.Controls.Add($btn)

    $mainForm.ShowDialog()
}

#click event
function Add_click() {
    CopyFolder
}

function CopyFolder() {
    $sourseFolder = "C:\tmp\tmp"
    $targetFolder = "C:\tmp\tmp2"

    $Logfile = "c:\tmp\a.log"

    robocopy $sourseFolder $targetFolder /tee /log:$Logfile
}

function ReadMode() {
    Write-Host Mode [1 for GUI mode]

    $mode = Read-Host

    if ($mode -eq 1) {
        createdMainForm
    } else {
        CopyFolder
    }
}

ReadMode
```

I want to capture the `robocopy` progress in a log file as well as in the console.

However only the log file capture the output, while the console "hangs" until end.

I found that is works smoothly when PowerShell does not display form, but simply runs the command.
The script works in two modes. enter 1 for "form mode" anything else for console mode, where the log actually written to console and file.

How can I use the form, and display the progress in the console?

Comment: execute robocopy on a background job, and receive the data at the end, this way the form will not freeze, also you can use timer to check on specific intervals whether the job completed and then get the data

Comment: It hard to offer something without seeing your code. Currently it sound like you want to write to pipe line from event handler of GUI window. It that is what you trying to do?

Comment: PetSerAI, yes you are right. the added the code in the question.

Comment: @OJNSim If you want to just display results in console, then easiest way will be to add `Out-Host` to yours command.

Comment: not sure I understand. Are you talking the the robocopy command? Can you give a sample? I also edited the question, it now includes 2 mode  script displaying the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the proper [`robocopy` parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> `/log:<LogFile>` Writes the status output to the log file (overwrites the existing log file).
>   …
>   `/tee` Writes the status output to the console window, as well as to the log file.

```
robocopy $s $t /tee /log:C:\path\to\your.log
```

As for updating the output of your embedded control, you probably need to refresh your form on a [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20233540/1630171):

```
$timer = New-Object Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.add_tick({$form.Refresh()})
```

Start the timer when calling `robocopy` and stop it after the command completes. Details will vary depending on your actual code (which you chose to omit).

---

**Edit:** I think I finally understood what you're trying to achieve and what problem you have getting there.

You're running `robocopy` from a scriptblock that is associated with a form element. Because of that STDOUT output doesn't go to the console. You need to take the `robocopy` output (the [success output stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)) and write it to the host console yourself:

```
function CopyFolder() {
    ...
    robocopy $sourseFolder $targetFolder /tee /log:$Logfile | Write-Host
}
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, or that I completely not following you...I modified the question with the relevant code. Maybe it will be more clear.

Comment: That tiny fragment isn't even remotely enough to make anything more clear. Please make that snippet a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok,  I felt is it enough. Sorry about that, I've edited the question. Now it contains a full script displaying the issue.tx.

Comment: @PetSerAl that did the trick. I now understand also what **PetSerAl**  suggestion with _out-host_. Solved