# Is there a way to run a popup window while a script runs?

Tags: powershell, popup, wsh

I am creating a gui, and want a popup to let you know it's busy, but then close when it's completed that specific task. The only thing i can find is the following...

```
$popup = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$popup.popup("Running Script, Please Wait....",0,"Running...",0x1)
```

But the issue is, this is waiting for a response, and then it will run the script. I am not asking for some to write me a script, but some guidelines on where to find this information.

I need powershell to popup a window, and then leave it up, while a script is ran, and then close it when the script is done running.
Would it be best just just have another windows form, that runs the script with a label on it? That seems like an excessive amount of work for a simple task. But it IS powershell...

Is there something like...

```
$popup = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$popup.popup("Running Script, Please Wait....",0,"Running...",0x1)
###RUN SCRIPT HERE...
$popup.close()
```

EDIT:::
To the question "Why am I trying to have a popup, instead of writeprogress or whatnot" ... The reason is because I am doing this in a gui. Not in the command line. So i need the gui to basically inform the person it's busy, some of the tasks can take over 6 hours to complete, and i don't want them clicking around, and doing other things while the current task at hand is running.

EDIT 2:::
I will leave this open, as the original question was not answered, but I created a work around with the following code.

```
$LabelAlert = New-Object system.windows.forms.label
$LabelAlert.Text = "Working, Please wait."
$LabelAlert.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,180)
$LabelAlert.width = 590
$LabelAlert.height = 25
$LabelAlert.Visible = $false
$LabelAlert.TextAlign = "TopCenter"
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelAlert)
$FormGroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$FormGroupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0) 
$FormGroupBox.width = 600
$FormGroupBox.height = 375
$Form.Controls.Add($FormGroupBox)
$startAlert = {
$LabelAlert.Visible = $true
$FormGroupBox.Visible = $false            
}
$stopAlert = {
$LabelAlert.Visible = $false
$FormGroupBox.Visible = $true            
}
```

Every form part was moved inside the group box. And the group box is the same size as my window.

And for every time consuming Script i run

```
&$startAlert
....script commands go here...
&$stopAlert
```

Comment: why are you trying to have a status window instead of just printing to the console?

Comment: Not tested but you might just be able to make a 'popup' using [Powershell Forms](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephap/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form/)... show with `$form.ShowDialog()` then close `$form.Close()`

Comment: I'm think that was the option. But seemed a bit over difficult for a simple thing.

Comment: See the following which you could use in your form for handling task checks & performing GUI updates when conditions are met (such as job complete) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233540/powershell-timer-update-gui

Comment: Thank you Adam, my gui updates my users when things are complete etc.. My problem was that you can mass click a button, or click multiple buttons, and instead of disabling everything in the script (50 lines of code per button action) i decided to make everything inside a groupbox, then I make the group box invisible, and have a label pop up explaining it's working.  I will consider your answer none the less.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Start-Job` to run the popup within a background job, which would allow the script to continue after it has appeared:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {   
    $popup = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
    $popup.popup("Running Script, Please Wait....",0,"Running...",0x1)
}

#Run script here..
```

But I can't see any way to force the popup to close at the end of your script (tried `Remove-Job -Force` and even `Stop-Process conhost -Force` but neither seemed to work).

As others have said though, the better option would be write status to the PowerShell window. You might want to look at the `Write-Progress` cmdlet which you can use to disply a progress bar over a running script.

Comment: I would like write-progress, but this is more of a stand alone gui, and should not rely on the powershell window for any visual clues.

Comment: The real answer is that PowerShell is probably not the right language for writing a GUI.

Comment: I don't have a choice, and besides that, the gui makes my users flawless. It's not a fancy gui. etc.. I think maybe ill just put everything in a groupbox, and then make it all vanish on each script...